# assigning elements to buffer and specific position in buffer - how to speed up / why are the different implementations so slow?

Tags: python

I'm trying to speed up the following code, where given a list of strings `str_list` I'm trying to convert the string into a number (`unpack`) and assign this number into the correct position of the nested list `data`. The dimensions of `data` are roughly `data[4][20][1024]`. Unfortunately, this function runs very slowly. Here's the code:

```
for abs_idx in range(nbr_elements):

    # get string
    this_element = str_list[abs_idx]

    # convert into number
    this_element = unpack('d', this_element)[0]

    # calculate the buffer number
    buffer_nbr = abs_idx / NBR_DATA_POINTS_PER_BUFFER_INT

    # calculate the position inside the buffer
    index_in_buffer = abs_idx % NBR_DATA_POINTS_PER_BUFFER_INT

    # write data into correct position
    data[file_idx][buffer_nbr][index_in_buffer] = this_element
```

I also tried the following alternative solution, which is even slower:

```
# convert each string into a number
unpacked_values = [unpack('d', str_list[j])[0] for j in range(nbr_elements)]
for abs_idx in range(nbr_elements):

    # calculate the buffer number
    buffer_nbr = abs_idx / NBR_DATA_POINTS_PER_BUFFER_INT

    # calculate the position inside the buffer
    index_in_buffer = abs_idx % NBR_DATA_POINTS_PER_BUFFER_INT

    # write data into correct position
    data[file_idx][buffer_nbr][index_in_buffer] = unpacked_values[abs_idx]
```

To my surprise, the next implementation is the slowest (I expected it to be the fastest):

```
# convert each string into a number
unpacked_values = [unpack('d', str_list[j])[0] for j in range(nbr_elements)]

# calculate all buffer numbers at once
buffer_ids = np.arange(nbr_elements) / NBR_DATA_POINTS_PER_BUFFER_INT

# calculate all positions inside the buffer at once
index_in_buffer_id = np.arange(nbr_elements) % NBR_DATA_POINTS_PER_BUFFER_INT

for abs_idx in range(nbr_elements):
    data[file_idx][buffer_ids[abs_idx]][index_in_buffer_id[abs_idx]] = unpacked_values[abs_idx]
```

Why are the successive implementations performing worse? Where are the individual bottlenecks? And how can I speed up my initial code?

**EDIT:** from my profiling tests, the following two steps are the bottleneck: running `unpack` and assigning the value to `data`. I don't know though how to speed-up these steps.

**EDIT2:** I need to use `unpack` because my strings are in hex.

**EDIT3:** `values = unpack("d" * n, "".join(str_list))` solves the problem with unpack being slow. Still, the assignment to data with the triple (original) or double (modified) nested loop eats up 50% of the time. Is there a way to reduce this time?

Comment: How many elements are you iterating over?

Comment: `nbr_elements` is in the order of 2000 to 20000.

Comment: Have you tried using something like `int(this_element.strip())` instead of `unpack('d', this_element)[0]`?  I'm not familiar with `unpack`, but it might have a large relative overhead if all it's doing is converting numbers in a string to an integer.  Also, is `data` just a nested list?

Comment: yes, `data` is a nested list.

Comment: If you're using hex, you can still use `int()`.  Just specify the base you're working in as the second argument: `int(this_element.strip(), 16)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some optimizations:

1. Unpack all stings at once
2. Get item data[file_idx] before loop

Try it:

```
n = len(str_list)
values = unpack("d" * n, "".join(str_list))

a = data[file_idx]

# Just to shorten this code sample
q = NBR_DATA_POINTS_PER_BUFFER_INT

for i in xrange(n):
    a[i / q][i % q] = values[i]
```

Btw, did you profile what part of the code takes the most time?

**UPDATE:**

```
n = len(str_list)
values = unpack("d" * n, "".join(str_list))

# Just to shorten this code sample
q = NBR_DATA_POINTS_PER_BUFFER_INT

data[file_idx] = [values[i:i+q] for i in xrange(0, n, q)]
```

Comment: `values = unpack("d" * n, "".join(str_list))` is great! however the assignment in the loop still eats up 50% of all time.

Comment: Check out my update. List comprehension is better than a regular loop with random array access.

Comment: the List comprehension is about 10 times faster! why is that?

Comment: why would `xrange` be beneficial here? shouldn't range be faster since we need the `i` values?

Answer (score 1):

Is this any faster? It reduces some lookups and does not need to make an intermediate list with the numbers for all the strings?

```
df = data[file_idx]
index = 0
for value in str_list:
    # not sure what unpack does... is there a faster function 
    # that does the same?
    number = unpack('d', value)[0]

    # calculate the buffer number
    buffer_nbr = index / NBR_DATA_POINTS_PER_BUFFER_INT

    # calculate the position inside the buffer
    index_in_buffer = index % NBR_DATA_POINTS_PER_BUFFER_INT

    # write data into correct position
    df[buffer_nbr][index_in_buffer] = number

    index += 1
```

Comment: the `df[buffer_nbr][index_in_buffer]` is still the slowest. is there a way to make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
df = data[file_idx]
index = 0
bufnr = 0
buf = df[0]
for value in str_list:
    # not sure what unpack does... is there a faster function 
    # that does the same?
    number = unpack('d', value)[0]

    buf[index] = number

    index += 1

    if index >= NBR_DATA_POINTS_PER_BUFFER_INT:
        index = 0
        bufnr += 1
        buf = df[bufnr]
```

Could it be that data is a dictionary instead of a list?